# create go mod project with github path no work in GoLand?

Tags: go, constructor, project, go-modules, goland

I created a go mod project with github path like that.
`go mod init github.com/txt2pdf`
But when I import my own package on Goland like below,  Goland  did not recognize my package.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTf5h.png)

This is the directory tree of my project。

```
|---go.mod
|---txt2pdf
|      |---txt2pdf.go
|---until
|    |---sysuntil
|    |       |---sysuntil.go
```

Does anyone tell me what is the reason for this，and how can i solve this
?

Comment: code is like blow
`
package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "github.com/txt2pdf/until/sysuntil"
)
func main() {
 fmt.Printf("system unique id %s\n", sysuntil.GetSysUniqID())
}
`

Comment: First, make sure you have GoLand 2019.3.2. Then, go to `Settings/Preferences | Go | Go Modules` and enable that checkbox. Finally, you need to move the `txt2pdf.go` file from its directory to one directory above, where the `go.mod` file is.

Comment: I updated Goland to 2019.3.2， and this problem was resolved. Thanks!!